# Adding syntax highlighting for a comment section in Emacs

Tags: emacs, regex, syntax-highlighting, elisp

I have the following

```lisp
(defun add-c-syntax-highlighting ()
  (font-lock-add-keywords nil '(
    ("\\<\\(\\-+\\)"   1 font-lock-warning-face prepend)
    ("\\<\\(FIXME\\):" 1 font-lock-warning-face prepend))))
```

with

```lisp
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'add-c-syntax-highlighting)
```

Testing on this simple buffer yields seemingly contradictory results:

```c
//FIXME:
//-------------
```

with only `FIXME` fontified.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My crystal ball tells me what you do wrong is copy&paste code you don't understand.  Looks like it's feeling sarcastic today, sorry, I promise I'll get a new one soon.

As for your problem, it's the `\\<` in your regexp, which is a special constructor which matches the beginning of a word, so it can never match in front of a `-` since words can only start with proper letters or digits.

Comment: I thought for sure it was the comment-start in the syntax table. I'll try this asap, thanks

Comment: Thanks again. I did try to find a reference for the syntax of the regular expression here; since `\\<` isn't standard, there *must* be some documentation on it.  I couldn't find it anywhere in the manual, however -- do you know where I should look?

Comment: @SeanAllred: Yes, see the [Elisp manual, node `Regexp Backslash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/elisp.html#Regexp-Backslash), and look for `\<`. And see node [`Syntax for Strings`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-for-Strings.html#Syntax-for-Strings) for info about doubling the backslash.

Comment: In the manual.  This is the `\<` special operator (where the `\` needs to be doubled in strings because it's a special escaping character in strings).

Comment: Related, before I ask another Q (in case it's another silly mistake like this...) - is there any reason it should work for this face? https://gist.github.com/vermiculus/6b2e6aad3c2ec14dc20d @Drew Ah, I suppose there's no (easy) way then to mark comment-only syntax.

Comment: @SeanAllred: I'm not sure what you're asking, and I'm no expert on syntactic font lock (*Stefan is*), but see [(elisp) `Syntactic Font Lock`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntactic-Font-Lock.html#Syntactic-Font-Lock) for info about it. An alternative is to use ad-hoc highlighting, "on top of" the font-lock highlighting of comments. You can use library [`highlight.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/HighlightLibrary), for example, to do that.