# Defining faces for syntax highlighting in Emacs

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting

This is a follow-up question to [Adding syntax highlighting for a comment section in Emacs](https://superuser.com/q/827818/160871).

I have the following face definition adapted from the definition of `font-lock-warning-face` in `font-lock.el`:

```
; (defface font-lock-warning-face
;   '((t :inherit error))
;   "Font Lock mode face used to highlight warnings."
;   :group 'font-lock-faces)
(defface my-code-section-face
  '((t :inherit font-lock-warning-face))
  "Face used for comment guards")

(defun add-c-syntax-highlighting ()
  (font-lock-add-keywords nil '(
    ("//\\-+" 0 (if t font-lock-warning-face
                  my-code-section-face) prepend))))
```

When I use `t` (`font-lock-warning-face`), the function works.  When `nil` (to use `my-code-section-face`), it does not.  I can only assume that it's a problem with [how I'm defining the face](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/elisp-manual-21-2.8/html_node/elisp_633.html), but I can't find an issue.  (Using `` ` `` vs. `'` makes no effective difference.)

Comment: In fact, I just noticed that when using `nil`, *all* font lock fails.

Comment: @Downvoter, have the common courtesy to leave a suggestion as to how to make this question better.  This is on-topic for this site.

Comment: I could be wrong, but normally a single quote inhibits evaluation inside a list, whereas a backtick permits evaluation -- when using the backtick, elements inside the list that need to be evaluated normally are preceded with a comma.  When using broad tags such as `syntax-highlighting`, you are bound to reach an audience unfamiliar with Emacs.

Comment: @lawlist Good to know, thanks. I don't think that'd have an impact in this case though.

Comment: @lawlist Well, I did include the [emacs] tag `:(` `font-lock` isn't one of them, as I recall

Comment: `(if` is inside the list -- so, a backtick would be needed (perhaps) instead of the single quote, and then use `,(if`

Comment: @lawlist The `if` is evaluated as one would immediately expect though; I simply use it as a quick-toggle construction.  That is, it works when the test is `t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like you need to quote `prepend`: `'prepend`, and move it outside the list:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("//\\-+" 0 whatever)) 'prepend)
```

And for testing, at least, get rid of all the stuff in `whatever` - just use something like `(0 'my-code-section-face t)`.

So something like this:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("//\\-+" (0 'my-code-section-face t))) 'prepend)
```

And you can always see whether your `defface` works the way you want, by using `M-x list-faces-display`.